# custom verify request page for next auth is not loading after sign in

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

using next auth with custom verify request page but it won't load after sign in (i.e. the page hangs or just stays on the same page it was already on) because of the following error, anyone know the reasoning?

```
API resolved without sending a response for /api/auth/verify-request?provider=email&type=email, this may result in stalled requests.
```

`/api/auth/verify-request.tsx`

```
const Verify = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="text-3xl">Check your email!!!!!!!!</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`[...nextauth].js`

```
export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    // Passwordless / email sign in
    EmailProvider({
      server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      maxAge: 3600,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      return token;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // (used for check email message)
  },
});
```

login form, tried both submitting form with csrfToken as well as tried signIn function by `next-auth/react`

```
signIn("email", { email: inputEmail });
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved. the custom verify page had to be outside the `api` folder